# Characterization of Compact Space via Continuous Function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ be a topological space. We know that if $X$ is compact and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function then $f(X)$ is bounded since the continuous image of a compact set is compact and any compact subset of a metric space is bounded.

My questions are (edited after David C. Ullrich's comment below),

> - What is(are) the necessary and/or sufficient condition(s) on  $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ so that if for any continuous $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ we can conclude that $f(X)$ is bounded then it would imply that $X$ is compact?
> - Let $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ be a topological space. If every continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is bounded **for all** metric space $(Y,d)$  then can we say that $X$ is compact?
> - Let $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ be a topological space. If **there exists** a metric space $(Y,d)$ such that every continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is bounded  then can we say that $X$ is compact?

Comment: The first uncountable ordinal is a counterexample.

Comment: This is not true in general for topological spaces. However, this is true for metric spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space $X$ is called pseudocompact when every real-valued continuous function on $X$ is bounded. This is a well-studied notion. Indeed a compact space, or even a countably compact space (every countable open cover has a finite subcover) is pseudocompact.

A classical theorem: for normal and $T_1$ spaces, countably compact and pseudocompact are equivalent.

The classical example of $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, is pseudocompact (and countably compact) and not compact. This shows that we cannot make the jump from countably compact to compact.

We can use Lindelöf (every cover has a countable subcover) as the gap property to compactness. So if we use at least Tychonoff spaces, a class of spaces where pseudocompactness and compactness coincide are the Lindelöf spaces.

Another class are the metric spaces, because for metric spaces countable compactness, pseudocompactness and compactness are equivalent.

A pseudocompact space has the property that every continuous map into every metric space is bounded. This follows from the equivalence for metric spaces and the fact that the continuous image of a pseudocompact space is pseudocompact.

So $\omega_1$ is also a counterexample to question 2, and a fortiori to 3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question...

You consider $\mathbb{R}_d$ with discrete topology and $[0,1]$ with euclidean topology. If $f:\mathbb{R}_d\longrightarrow[0,1]$ is a function, then $f$ is continuos and bounded, but $\mathbb{R}_d$ is not compact.

Comment: $Y$ is any metric space, i.e., $Y$ varies over the class of all metric spaces. See the edit. I hope that is clearer now.

Comment: Yes...Now the problem is more difficult! xD

Answer (score 1):

The first uncountable ordinal $X = \omega_1$, with its order topology, is a counterexample for the second question (and hence also the third).  It's well known that $X$ is not compact, yet any continuous function $h : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded (in fact, it's eventually constant).  Now if $(Y,d)$ is any metric space and $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, fix a point $y_0 \in Y$ and let $g : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $g(y) = d(y,y_0)$, which is continuous.  Then $h = g \circ f$ is a continuous map from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, hence bounded; say $h(x) \le M$ for all $x \in X$.  That means $d(y_0, f(x)) \le M$ for all $x \in X$, so that $f(X)$ is bounded.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say a space is RB if every continuous real-valued function is bounded.

You ask for necessary and sufficient conditions such that RB implies compact. The word "implies" is a little funny; what people often mean by it is difficult if not impossible to define precisely.

The only precise definition of "A implies B" that I know is "A is false or B is true". If we take that as the definition of "implies" then the answer to your question is that RB implies compact if and only if $X$ is compact or there exists an unbounded real-valued continuous function on $X$.

Almost surely not an answer to what you really wanted to know, but possibly the best answer that question is going to get. (The best answer that actually gives a necessary and sufficient condition.)

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "The only precise definition of "A implies B" that I know is "A is false or B is true"." Can you clarify?

Comment: @user170039 I don't understand what you want me to clarify. That _is_ the only precise definition of "implies" that I know...

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should give a better answer to the first question.

Comment: Why do you think that it *is* precise? For me [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrx_TJ_crMAhWJcI4KHS_sBnYQFghtMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FImplies.html&usg=AFQjCNHbEBVo_1iH_c4aBhSSLxeMBhPMmg) is precise enough.

Comment: The definition I gave is the same as the definition there. "In classical logic, A implies B is an abbreviation for not A or B".

Comment: That's what I wanted you to clarify. Why *exactly* is your definition "same" (in the sense you have used it) as that I have linked?

Comment: You want me to clarify _exactly_ why "not A or B" is the same as "A is false or B is true"? You're serious?

Comment: Yes. I think so. I don't see any compelling reason to assume that the meaning (or sense) conveyed by the two expressions "not A or B" is *same* as "A is false or B is true". If you do please tell me the *precise* reason(s) (assuming it exists).

Comment: I have a hard time "clarifying" that, because I can't imagine how it can be unclear. Can you explain what's bothering you about this? Like explain how you're interpreting the two phrases so they seem to perhaps mean something different?

Comment: Oh. One possible problem is this: "not A or B" is meant as "(not A) or B", not "not (A or B)". (Which btw is exactly why I didn't put it that way - one can't misparse "A is false or B is true" in the same manner...)

Comment: Of course, any question of the kind “what characterises objects with property X” can be answered with “property X”. True but not very helpful.

Comment: @CarstenS No? It seemed likely to me that the OP did not realize that "RP implies compact" was the same as "either $X$ is compact or $X$ supports an unbounded continuous real-valued function". I appear to have been right about that - look at the comments, he didn't believe it. And pointing out that his question is equivalent to that rephrasing seems helpful to me, because it shows that he probably should not expect to get the sort of answer he was hoping for.

Comment: "..he probably should not expect to get the sort of answer he was hoping for." - why?

Comment: @user170039 Given that yesterday you were complaining about "A is false or B is true" being less than precise, when there was simply nothing imprecise about it (no, even if it _were_ different from what you read on mathworld that would not indicate it was not precise). I'm not going to spend any time debating matters of opinion with you.

Comment: It's surprising that you spent time to write this obviously unhelpful answer (which I think would be better left as a comment). By the way, I don't see anywhere mentioning that your definition of implies is not precise. I only wanted you to clarify the reason for which you think that your definition was precise.

Comment: Is this answer some kind of joke?